# An HTML link to change values in a database: booleans, strings or integers using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I would like to create a HTML link which when clicked on will change the value of a boolean, string or integer in the database using Laravel.

Comment: Without refreshing the page or it doesn't matter?

Comment: It doesn't matter. As long as it is clicked on, it will change the value in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to make a route for that so lets assume this

```php
Route::get('change/{changable_id}', 'ChangeController@change')->name('change');
```

and then in your blade file

```php
<a href="{{ route('change', $model->id) }}">Change the value</a>
```

Note that `$model->id` is the id of thing that you want to change in database

then in `ChangeController`

```php
 public function change($id)
    {
        YourModel::find($id)->update([
            'key_of_the_thing_that_you_want_to_change' => 'new_value'
        ]);

        return back();
    }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thank you so much @AH.Pooladvand, you're a true developer indeed. How can I indicate that my question is solved and also give the name of the person that solved it?

Comment: By clicking on Check icon